# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) - dotnet MAUI, with Shiny 3# Alpha Job on Android

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, .net-maui

Don't have a lot of experience with debugging issues with Android. Have built an app with dotnet MAUI, and since adding a Shiny job to do a Web API call, I'm getting these errors in my logcat:

```
[07-20 08:11:56.776 1452:4329 D/ConnectivityService]
requestNetwork for uid/pid:10515/17091 activeRequest: null callbackRequest: 1115 [NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10515 RequestorUid: 10515 RequestorPkg: com.devonuto.myapp UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]] callback flags: 0 order: 2147483647

[07-20 08:11:56.782 1452:2148 D/WifiNetworkFactory]
got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10515 RequestorUid: 10515 RequestorPkg: com.devonuto.myapp UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]

[07-20 08:11:56.782 1452:2148 D/UntrustedWifiNetworkFactory]
got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10515 RequestorUid: 10515 RequestorPkg: com.devonuto.myapp UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]

[07-20 08:11:56.783 1452:2148 D/OemPaidWifiNetworkFactory]
got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10515 RequestorUid: 10515 RequestorPkg: com.devonuto.myapp UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]

[07-20 08:11:56.793 17091:17116 F/libc]
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x78 in tid 17116 (WM.task-4), pid 17091 (uto.myapp)

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
Cmdline: com.devonuto.myapp

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
pid: 17091, tid: 17116, name: WM.task-4  >>> com.devonuto.myapp <<<

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #00 pc 000000000010a950  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 7126846382da0d3e3df8b79b9e84b9aa48aaaf36)

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #01 pc 000000000010a798  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 7126846382da0d3e3df8b79b9e84b9aa48aaaf36)

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #02 pc 000000000009ab9c  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_runtime_invoke+52) (BuildId: 7126846382da0d3e3df8b79b9e84b9aa48aaaf36)

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #03 pc 000000000002af5c  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::Java_mono_android_Runtime_register(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, _jclass*, _jstring*)+276) (BuildId: f2b35ad7b68e8f683693b4693ca43b2d312da134)

[07-20 08:12:10.219 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #06 pc 000000000090d5c0  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (crc6401c279856d6dfa9c.ShinyJobWorker.<clinit>+16)

[07-20 08:12:10.220 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #23 pc 00000000003db2a8  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback+20)

[07-20 08:12:10.220 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #29 pc 00000000003df47e  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker+734)

[07-20 08:12:10.220 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #35 pc 00000000003df192  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run+32)

[07-20 08:12:10.220 17119:17119 F/DEBUG]
      #41 pc 00000000003ee5ac  /data/app/~~vGtfU8056GdzOPsvkH9Xwg==/com.devonuto.myapp-9GAii6I21Z8cSs5-r99zdw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run+4)

[07-20 08:12:18.887 1452:4329 D/ConnectivityService]
ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(uid/pid:10515/17091, [NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10515 RequestorUid: 10515 RequestorPkg: com.devonuto.myapp UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ]], android.os.BinderProxy@fb80569)

[07-20 08:12:18.887 1452:3898 W/ActivityManager]
Scheduling restart of crashed service com.devonuto.myapp/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService in 1000ms for connection

[07-20 08:12:18.887 1452:2155 D/ConnectivityService]
releasing NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1116, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10515 RequestorUid: 10515 RequestorPkg: com.devonuto.myapp UnderlyingNetworks: Null] ] (release request)
```

The developer of Shiny isn't interested in helping with issues using Alpha releases, but basically I just want to work out if this is something I have done wrong, or a bug with the Shiny Alpha MAUI release?

in MauiProgram.cs I have:

```
 // Shiny Jobs
 builder.Services.AddJob(new JobInfo(typeof(DataRefreshJob), nameof(DataRefreshJob), false)
 {
      RequiredInternetAccess = InternetAccess.Any,     
 }, true);
```

And in my DataRefreshJob.cs, the Run task is essentially:

```
public async Task Run(JobInfo jobInfo, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    _service = AppService.GetService<IMethodService>();
    _ = _service.GetScheduledApiData();
}
```

Looking at the LogCat, is it having exception with the ConnectivityService? Something to do with: RequiredInternetAccess = InternetAccess.Any?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to debug it and find which line caused this error?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT No, I put a breakpoint on  var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder(); (the first line of MauiProgram.cs, the breakpoint hits, but then a couple seconds later the error is thrown. So it's something running on a different thread, or on the device that is causing the error.  There doesn't appear to be anywhere I can place a breakpoint to capture the error before it happens.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project? In addition, does the other projects work well?

Comment: Yes, many many times. What other projects?

Comment: Such as a new small project.

Comment: I haven't tried to create a new project using the jobs, but since it's not all the time, I'll have to run it for a few days to see if it occurs.

Comment: Do you mean the project will work well sometimes?

Comment: It works most of the time, but occasionally throws these errors in the logs.

Comment: Additionally, when calling web APIs from the app, it throws errors like "ERROR: Unable to resolve host "<url>": No address associated with hostname" from time to time.  Which after searching on here, makes me think there is an issue with the job accessing network connectivity status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may stumble upon this, it was not caused by the Shiny Job, instead was caused by using SemaphoreSlims used to control concurrent calls to an API.

Job appeared to be the source, as it was kicking off a bunch of async API calls. When those calls hit the SemaphoreSlim waitasync() it was causing the SEGV_MAPERR.

Removing the use of semaphore slim, and queing the async API calls up instead solved the issue.